# Number of rectangles in a grid of perimeter at least/at most $X$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Inspired by this question: [Number of rectangles in a grid of size at least W×H](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674022/number-of-rectangles-in-a-grid-of-size-at-least-w-times-h)

As before, the number of rectangles of all sizes in a grid is given by

$$\binom{m+1}{2}\binom{n+1}{2}$$

What if there was perimeter restriction? For example, number of rectangles with perimeters less than (or more than, or exactly equal to) $X$?

What are the general solutions?